# Ajax error does not contain a response

Tags: javascript, ajax, error-handling, axios

I'm having a strange issue with Ajax calls. I'm using the Axios library to make ajax calls as shown below:

```
    axios.get( configData.endpoint, configData ).then(function (response) {

    // log ajax return
    logger.logAjaxCall(response, config, component);

    console.log(response.data);

    }).catch(function (error) {

    console.log(error);

    });
```

However, the error does not contain a response. The API is passing a response which is also shown in the browser (Chrome in this case). But the error in the catch function above, contains only the config {} and a request {}. The error in the catch callback returns:

```
Error: Network Error
at createError (eval at <anonymous> (app.js:2306), <anonymous>:16:15)
at XMLHttpRequest.handleError (eval at <anonymous> (app.js:2285), <anonymous>:87:14)
```

If I JSON.stringify the error it shows only a config{} and a request{} but no response.

Any help is appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Use `console.log(error.response);` to get the response you send from the API. Reason is that `console.log` output the error which represented in string, not the object structure.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I tried that and response is undefined. That property does not exist on the error, yet the browser picks up the 404 or other error statuses.